# Remote Shutdown without (!) RPC Service

Tags: wmi, rpc, shutdown

There are different ways of shutting down a computer remotely.

Here are three I know of:

1. Invoking the Shutdown method of the Win32_OperatingSystem class through a remote WMI connection
2. Using the Microsoft Windows shutdown.exe
3. Letting your (whatever).exe copy itself to the systemfolder on the target machine, register itself as a service and start it remotely with parameters so that it initiates a local shutdown.

**Number 3** is why sysinternals does, e.g. However, it requires that you have file & printer sharing active so that it is able to copy itself to the target and invoke the service.

**Number 2** works almost everywhere... but also needs to have file & printer sharing being enabled. Because: This activates the RPC service which is needed for remotely invoking the shutdown.

As far as I can tell, even **Number 1**, the WMI solution, not only needs WMI installed on the target, but also the RPC service enabled.

My problem is:
I need a solution that allows me to shutdown a remote computer **without RPC** being enabled on it.

Is there a way?

Note: A way within a context of a business solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use [IPMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface) for such tasks.  It requires hardware support though.  We used it for lights-out management over a serial port in a solution a few years ago.  We had some issues with the hardware support for *soft shutdown* since it requires some integration with the OS.  From what I remember, you can mimic the hardware reaction to pressing the power button using a network packet sent by an [IPMI utility](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipmiutil/). HTH.